# How to handle direct contact offers? (Unsolicited Offer)

Tags: discussion

In this question a user is offering his contact:

**Tracking contact form submissions for different pages with Google Analytics**
[Tracking contact form submissions for different pages with Google Analytics](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/tracking-contact-form-submissions-for-different-pages-with-google-analytics/2280#2280)

Does the answer have to be removed or edited to remove the contact?

Answer (score 3):

That question already had upvoted answers. I took the liberty of deleting the answer altogether as it seemed to be more about self promotion. I find this unacceptable.